# How should Puppet plugins be configured?

Tags: puppet

If I externalise my Puppet module config to a directory outside of Puppet by adding the modulepath / manifestdir settings:

```
[main]  
  pluginsync=true 
  modulepath=/home/user/project/etc/puppet/modules 
  manifestdir=/home/user/project/etc/puppet/manifests
```

the agents log the following error:

"Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from source(s) puppet://my-dns-name/plugins"

so looks as if they no longer seem to be able to find the Facter facts I have installed in $modulepath//lib/facter ?

If I comment out the modulepath / manifestdir settings and copy the configuration back to the /etc/puppet install directory the agents work fine.

Do I maybe need to set the pluginsource setting also and if so, where to? 
Any pointers gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the permissions on your home directory restricted, e.g. to 0750?  The puppetmaster will typically run as a dedicated `puppet` user rather than root, so it probably can't read a private home directory.

The other possibility is SELinux if you're using it.  I'd expect that the files in your home directory aren't labeled to permit access by a puppetmaster process.  Do you see any AVC denials in syslog?

Comment: Awesome, thanks you m0dlx, should have been obvious that permissions were the issue, but was getting confused by the way Puppet writes the Facter facts out to /var/lib/puppet dir. Thanks and best, Drew